# selenium with aliexpress transaction-history

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I try to scrape transaction-history from aliexpress as below , but output for order1, order2 and country show only session and element, not show example as order = "1 piece" or country = "FR"

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Modyle-2017-New-Fashion-Her-King-and-His-Queen-Stainless-Steel-Wedding-Rings-for-Women-Men/32827876813.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.2.b0db7b0bXHTbvz&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_1_10065_10068_10890_319_10546_317_10548_5730311_10696_453_10084_454_10083_5729211_10618_10307_538_537_536_10059_10884_10887_100031_321_322_10103,searchweb201603_51,ppcSwitch_0&algo_expid=0ffd4f5b-afac-45be-ac7e-a0c97769e137-0&algo_pvid=0ffd4f5b-afac-45be-ac7e-a0c97769e137&transAbTest=ae803_3")
time.sleep(20)
rows = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="j-transaction-feedback"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr'))

print(rows)

a1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="j-transaction-feedback"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div/i')

order1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="j-transaction-feedback"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div[1]')
order2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="j-transaction-feedback"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div[1]')
country = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="j-transaction-feedback"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div/div/b')

print(order1)
print(order2)
print(country)
```

output

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.7 /Users/nayot/PycharmProjects/aliexpress/test2.py
20
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="abbb90b60a6a662884cb1642398d2ec4", element="0.5214822951220621-22")>]
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="abbb90b60a6a662884cb1642398d2ec4", element="0.5214822951220621-23")>]
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="abbb90b60a6a662884cb1642398d2ec4", element="0.5214822951220621-24")>]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: did you try to use oder1.text ?

Comment: already , not ok. Do you know how to fix it ?

Comment: sorry nothing comes to my mind now ... but I can bet it should be .text , because you want a text thats in div

Comment: Hi StyleZ, It's ok now as your suggestion to text, firstly I put in wrong place . Thankssssss :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the .text attribute is the right way to go as you've tried and Stylez pointed out. However it appears that you have not selected the element correctly, as

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath
```

returns an empty list. If you want to select only one element you should use

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath
```

(notice the missing "s"). If you use the list approach you obviously need to access element directly via the index.

Also note, that you do not necessarily need to enter the whole XPath.

```
'//div[@class="order-num"]'
```

should normally work as well. Again, that is only if you actually select the element on the website correctly.

Comment: My pleasure. Also note that selenium is extremely tricky. If you fail to get an element, for example, the element may be nested in an iFrame, in which case you need to tell the driver to switch to said iFrame.
If all else fails, you can always get .page_source and use BeautifulSoup to parse the text, if it is possible.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I'm newbie for programmer and firstly I also use BeautifulSoup but it can't see the table same as in page_source so I moved to selenium ?_? , how do you think ?   And <i class="s-member-level sm-level-A0"></i> if I need to show "s-member-level sm-level-A0" what should i do ? because this one doesn't have text.